# How to Append VariableID - AndroidX

Tags: java, android, loops, append

I want to set a variable that was appended every time it's looping, how to do that?

```
Model Test1;
    Model Test2;
    Model Test3;
    Model Test4;
    Model Test5;
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
        Test+[i].add("Cat");
    }
```

so it will become this

```
Test1.add("Cat");
Test2.add("Cat");
Test3.add("Cat");
```

Comment: add those objects to an array and then loop through the array

Comment: can't it's model object

Comment: What you are trying to do is possible but the way you are trying to do is not possible. Follow what @ChrisGong said.

Comment: ArrayList<ModelDiscoverNormalGameInfo> modelDiscoverNormalGameInfo1 = new ArrayList<ModelDiscoverNormalGameInfo>();
    ArrayList<ModelDiscoverNormalGameInfo> modelDiscoverNormalGameInfo2 = new ArrayList<ModelDiscoverNormalGameInfo>();
    ArrayList<ModelDiscoverNormalGameInfo> modelDiscoverNormalGameInfo3 = new ArrayList<ModelDiscoverNormalGameInfo>(); My Variable is like this @Thangadurai

Answer (score 0):

You can use HashMap just like that

```
     HashMap<String, Model> test = new HashMap<>();
      for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
        test.put("test"+(i+1),new Model().add("Cat"));
       }
```

Fetch your object from hashmap by key

```
         test.get("keyName);
```

Comment: it's doesn't work modelDiscoverMixs.add(new ModelDiscoverMix(DISCOVERXGAME_LAYOUT, "INITEMAGAME", test.get("test1"), "a"));

Comment: you can also use modelDiscoverMixs.add(new ModelDiscoverMix(DISCOVERXGAME_LAYOUT, "INITEMAGAME", (Modal) test.get("test1"), "a")); in case u declare the object u can cast  modal class to object